# Installing yum on linux results in no module named yum error despite only have python 2.7

Tags: linux, python, kali-linux, yum

I am running on Kali 2020.2 (kali-rolling). I am trying to install things using `yum`. However, whenever I try and run such commands I receive the error :

```
    There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
    required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

       No module named yum

    Please install a package which provides this module, or 
    verify that the module is installed correctly.

    It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
    current version of Python, which is:
    2.7.18 (default, Apr 20 2020, 20:30:41) 
    [GCC 9.3.0]

    If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
    the yum faq at:
      http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

In my search for a solution, I found that it seems most people are getting the issue that they have multiple versions of python installed, yet I only have the one (2.7).
Despite my issue being different, I tried these various solutions, but they didn't work.

Furthermore, I attempted the solutions from the site:https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21199 to no avail.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Well, Kali is based on Debian, so why don't you want to install things with `apt`?

Answer (score 2):

`yum` is a package manager for the RedHat family (RHEL, Fedora, CEntOS...).

Kali is Debian derivative and uses a different package management scheme, with a different package format... Using `yum` and RedHat repos on Kali will likely break things.

If you see installation instructions using `yum` or `rpm`, try, in that order:

- See if there is a like-named package in your Debian repo (it is still useful to check that it installs the same things). If so you can install it using `apt` or `apt-get`.
- Search for a downloadable .DEB that you install with `dpkg`
- Download the `.rpm` and convert or install it using [`alien`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto).
- Otherwise all these packages are available as source and can be recompiled and installed locally.